# How to integrate a script of an external git repo into the grunt package.json

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I just stumbled upon grunt and i wonder how to integrate

1. local JS Scripts into package.json and
2. how to load an external JS Library ( for example) from git

Is the package.json the right place for that? How should I include external JS Libs in my project with grunt?

Comment: You can use NPM and load the modules to Grunt  - Most external libraries are grunt plugin . If you want to load a custom Repo which is a Nodejs Project then the Nodejs Require system still works . Let me know which one you are looking I will add it to the answer

Comment: hey thank you very much! this is the repo https://github.com/creativelive/appear

Comment: Can you explain more on what you want to to with this library and grunt integeration

Comment: I want to use this library together with reactjs. the purpose is that i want to have a handler if something appears in the visible area of the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Grunt-Execute](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-execute) to execute the external JS for your project . From the comments the [Appear](http://github.com/creativelive/appear) doesnt sound like a script to me. Not sure how it fits in Build cycle